# How do you structure a clean architecture project with multiple features like invoices, consumption, user management etc without mediatr

Tags: clean-architecture

I would like to implement clean architecture in my project.
I have different features like UserManagement, InvoiceManagement for the customers.
Should I create multiple class libraries for Domain, Application and Infrastructure in .net 6 or have 1 class library like Domain and add feature wise folders in it ?
What is a recommended approach ?
Also I dont want to use MediatR in my project.